# 1080 x 1920 layout folder

Tags: android, layout, pixel

I am trying to design the layouts of an app for all screen sizes. The current phone I am testing it with is Vodaphone Smart Ultra 6. It's resolution is

```
1080 x 1920 pixels (~401 ppi pixel density)
```

For those dimensions I know that

```
layout-normal-xxhdpi
```

should be used. However, in my case my phone doesn't detect any changes I do in the above layout.

However, everything works fine with

```
    layout-normal-xhdpi
```

I thought that the last layout is used only for `720x1280`

I think I should use something like `layout-sw360`. So how should I calculate the smallest width for my phone,I described in the beginning?

Thank you,

Theo.

**EDIT**

I think i know what is happening. Google states that

```
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
```

My phone has a dpi of 401. So that's why xxhdpi's layout changes,don't affect my phone.

But again if I am wrong please correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: "For those dimensions I know that `layout-normal-xxhdpi` should be used" -- using a density qualifier (`-xxhdpi`) for anything other than `drawable` and `mipmap` resources is a code smell. "I thought that the last layout is used only for 720x1280" -- screen density (pixels per inch) and screen resolution (pixels) are not the same thing.

Comment: 401 ppi is really in between 320 dpi and 480 dpi. So, it could be normalized to one or the other one. Empirically, you determined that it's xhdpi instead of xxhdpi. But this has nothing to do with the resolution. Off-topic: great device!